# Reciprocal sum of sequences with Sylvester-like quadratic recurrence

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

[Sylvester's sequence](https://oeis.org/A000058) is defined recursively with $e_1 = 2$ and $e_{n + 1} = e_n^2 - e_n + 1$. The sequence also satisfies the recurrence $e_{n + 1} = e_1 \cdots e_n + 1$. These recurrences let us compute the remarkable sum $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{e_k} = \frac{e_{n + 1} - 2}{e_{n + 1} - 1}.$$ For instance, compute $R_{n + 1} - R_n$ where $R_n = (e_n - 2) / (e_n - 1)$, then sum over $n$.

**Question:** In general, given a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying the equivalent recurrences
\begin{align*}
    a_{n + 1} &= \prod_{k = 1}^n a_k + \beta \\
    a_{n + 1} &= a_n^2 - \beta a_n + \beta,
\end{align*}
can we evaluate $\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^{-1}$ in closed-form? This is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2523930/sylvesters-sequence-and-a-similar-sum), but more restricted.

I suspect that the answer is nice because of the following calculation:
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^{-1} &= \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{a_1 \cdots a_{k - 1} a_{k + 1} \cdots a_n}{a_1 \cdots a_n} \\
    &= \frac{P_n}{a_{n + 1} - \beta}.
\end{align*}
The sequence $P_n$ is some messy sum that I believe could reduce.

Using a trick similar to the one above, it is "routine" to show that $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{(\gamma - \beta)(a_k - 1)}{(a_k - \beta) a_k} = \frac{a_{n + 1} - \gamma}{a_{n + 1} - \beta} - \frac{a_1 - \gamma}{a_1 - \beta}$$ for any $\gamma$. When $\beta = 1$ we can take $\gamma = 2$ to evaluate $\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k^{-1}$, but this only works for $\beta = 1$.